# list output truncated - How to show full listLearners()

Tags: r, mlr

In `mlr` package i try to see all options of

```
listLearners()
```

But I see just first 6 elements. I try other methods like

```
listLearners("regr")[1:10, c("class","package")]
```

But however

```
       class      package
1  regr.blackboost mboost,party
2     regr.cforest        party
3       regr.ctree        party
4    regr.cvglmnet       glmnet
5 regr.featureless          mlr
6    regr.gamboost       mboost
... (10 rows, 2 cols)
```

How to fix it? Global options? Length?

Comment: `View(listLearners())`?

Comment: thanks! @MikeH. it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mlr uses the [`printHead()` function from the BBmisc package](https://github.com/berndbischl/BBmisc/blob/master/R/printHead.R) quite heavily for printing objects. Note that it has a parameter `n` that allows you to specify how many things to show. You can set this when printing, for example

```
print(listLearners(), n = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following preserves the formatting in the console window:

```
 as.data.frame(listLearners("regr")[1:10, c("class","package")])
```